# Enqueue and Dequeue Functions

Tags: c, queue, enqueue

So short context, I need to dequeue my elements of the queue and enqueue them to a temporary queue. When the original queue is empty and the elements are inside the temporary queue, I need to enqueue them back to the original queue. My enqueue function works fine but I think my dequeue function lacks some arguments and I can't think of it. After executing the different functions that call dequeue, the program will always terminate after the complete execution of a function.

Here is a piece of code that addresses the same problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct person{
    char firstname[30], lastname[30], sex[10];
    int hfeet, hinches;
    float weight;
}Person;

typedef struct node *nodeptr;

typedef struct node{
    Person data;
    nodeptr next;
}Node;

//Function Declarations
void Add(nodeptr *queue, nodeptr *tail);
void Enqueue(nodeptr *queue, nodeptr *element, nodeptr *tail);
nodeptr Dequeue(nodeptr *queue, nodeptr *head);
void DisplayAll(nodeptr *queue, nodeptr *head, nodeptr *tail);

int main(void) {
    nodeptr queue1 = NULL;
    nodeptr h = NULL;
    nodeptr t = NULL;
    int ch;

    while(1){
    printf("Enter choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);

        switch (ch) {
            case 1:
                Add(&queue1, &t);
                break;
            case 2:
                DisplayAll(&queue1, &h, &t);
                break;  
        }
    } 
    return 0;
 }

void Enqueue(nodeptr *queue, nodeptr *element, nodeptr *tail) {
    if (*tail == NULL) {
       *queue = *element;
       *tail = *element;
     } 
    else {
       (*tail)->next = *element;
       *tail = *element;
    }
}

nodeptr Dequeue(nodeptr *queue, nodeptr *head) {
    nodeptr current = *queue;
    *queue = (*queue)->next;
    *head = *queue;
     return current;
}

void Add(nodeptr *queue, nodeptr *tail){

    nodeptr queue1 = *queue;
    nodeptr t = *tail;
    bool chk = *chked;
    char first[30], last[30];
    int inch, feet;
    float mass;

    nodeptr element = (nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));

        printf("\nEnter First Name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(first);
        strcpy(element->data.firstname, first);
        printf("Enter Last Name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(last);
        strcpy(element->data.lastname, last);
        Enqueue(&queue1, &element, &t);
        printf("\nData successfully added.");
        getch();
        system("cls");
    
        *queue = queue1;
        *tail = t;
        *chked = chk;
}

void DisplayAll (nodeptr *queue, nodeptr *head, nodeptr *tail){

    nodeptr queue1 = *queue;
    nodeptr h = *head;
    nodeptr t = *tail;
    nodeptr tempqueue = NULL;
    nodeptr h2 = NULL;
    nodeptr t2 = NULL;  

    while (queue1 != NULL){
        nodeptr current = Dequeue(&queue1, &h);
        printf("\nFirst Name\tLast Name");
        printf("\n%s\t%s", current->data.firstname, current->data.lastname);
        getch();
        Enqueue(&tempqueue, &current, &t2);
    }

    while (tempqueue != NULL){
        nodeptr current = Dequeue(&tempqueue, &h2);
        Enqueue(&queue1, &current, &t);
    }

    *queue = queue1;
    *head = h;
    *tail = t;
    getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

After Displaying the elements inside the queue, the program will exit.

Comment: Please try to create a small and simple program, a [mre], to test the queue in isolation. That will make it much easier to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program.

Comment: And whenever it comes to any kind of pointers, lists and similar, I recommend you use pencil and paper to keep track of all your variable and pointers and where they point. Draw labeled boxes for variables and nodes, and arrows for pointers and links. Erase and redraw arrows as you change the corresponding pointer or link in your program.

Comment: On another couple of notes: It's explicitly mentioned in the C specification that passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` leads to *undefined behavior*. And ***never ever*** use `gets`! It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that it has even been removed from the C language.

Comment: @BrownyChewy – 
`In function 'Add': error: 'chked' undeclared`

Comment: In your `DisplayAll` function, what is the purpose of the `head` and `tail` arguments? Why do you have the assignments to `*queue`, `*head` and `*tail` at the end of the function? What problem would that solve? You seem to be doing quite a lot in a function that is supposed to only *display* something. Please make function names reflect what the functions are actually doing. And please don't do too much in a single function, it's better if a function only does one single thing.